# Adding another dimension to array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of TLDs and prices, and now I want to be able to add a classification i.e. 'Australian','New Zealand','Industry' to the domains but I am having troubles adding the extra dimension.

The array I have is

```
$domains = array(
'.com.au' => '19.98', 
'.melbourne' => '90.00', 
'.academy' => '45.00', 
'.accountants' => '120.00', 
'.ac.nz' => '36.75');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$domains = array(
'.com.au' => array(
'country' => 'Australia',
'sector' => 'Industry',
'price' => '19.98'
), 
);
```

Is this a beginning on what you're looking for ?

Comment: Spot on, the problem is we have 221 TLD so I was looking how it could b done programatically

Comment: It could be done programmatically but you need for that to post an example of what you expect as result.

Answer (score 0):

Is this code ok for you?

```
<?php
$domains = array(
'.com.au' => '19.98', 
'.melbourne' => '90.00', 
'.academy' => '45.00', 
'.accountants' => '120.00', 
'.ac.nz' => '36.75');

$newDomains = [];
foreach($domains as $key=>$value){
    if($key == '.com.au'){
        $newDomains[$key]['TLD'] = $value;
        $newDomains[$key]['Industry'] = 'blabal';
    }else{
        $newDomains[$key] = $value;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($newDomains);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Or even:

```
$domains = array(
'.com.au' => '19.98', 
'.melbourne' => '90.00', 
'.academy' => '45.00', 
'.accountants' => '120.00', 
'.ac.nz' => '36.75');


$industryArray = array(
    '.com.au' => 'blabla'
    );


$newDomains = [];
foreach($domains as $key=>$value){

    if(isset($industryArray[$key])){
        $newDomains[$key]['TLD'] = $value;
        $newDomains[$key]['Industry'] = $industryArray[$key];
    }else{
        $newDomains[$key] = $value;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($newDomains);
echo '</pre>';
```

The result is:

```
array(5) {
  [".com.au"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["TLD"]=>
    string(5) "19.98"
    ["Industry"]=>
    string(6) "blabla"
  }
  [".melbourne"]=>
  string(5) "90.00"
  [".academy"]=>
  string(5) "45.00"
  [".accountants"]=>
  string(6) "120.00"
  [".ac.nz"]=>
  string(5) "36.75"
}
```